# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) using MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am new to php and can't seem to solve this issue that I have. 
Basically I want to build a data base and access it on my website. 
I downloaded MAMP on my mac to run the site locally until I publish my site. 
I made a database using phpmyadmin.
The database is a table that consists of 5 rows and 4 columns (but will increase in the future). 
The following is my code to connect to database called hello:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "hello";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
echo "connected to database";
}
?>
```

However I get this error as it seems that I cannot connect to the database.

```
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have tried different things like adding in a space for the password or setting it to root but they don't seem to work. 
I dont understand how there is a password set on the database when I never set one.

Comment: If your password is correct, try 127.0.0.1 as host/servername

Comment: @A.Blub — No! If the password was correct, it would work. If the hostname was wrong, it wouldn't be able to connect. The error message shows it is connecting and then the username/password is being rejected.

Comment: @Quentin you dont understand MySQL user-rights. There are entries for the user "Source". The Machine finds localhost and 127.0.0.1. But if his entry missing the word "localhost", then it block this try. If there is 127.0.0.1 missing too, he isnt able to login with this IP either

Comment: @A.Blub — MAMP's default permissions are set to allow `localhost`. Using an IP address instead of `localhost` is a bad idea because it forces a TCP/IP connection instead of a UNIX socket.

Comment: @Quentin you said that he would have an error message for his connection. Thats wrong. Default are allways 2 entries -> localhost and 127.0.0.1 but there can be differences. Thats not a new problem and may be his too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I dont understand how there is a password set on the database when I never set one.

Because MAMP sets one by default.

[Their documentation also tells you how to change it](http://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-Mac/How-Tos/Change-the-password-of-the-MySQL-root-user/):

> 1. Open the Mac OS Terminal Application located in your /Applications/Utilities directory.
> 2. Enter the following command line: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password
>      [NewPassword]
> 3. Replace [NewPassword] with your new password.
> 4. Please bear in mind that you also have to change the phpMyAdmin configuration and probably your own php scripts to use the newly
>      created MySQL password. For changing the phpMyAdmin configuration edit
>      the following file and update the password. /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php

… don't write applications that log in as root though. [Create a new user](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql) with just as many permissions as they need.

Comment: Thanks man I've been stuck on that for ages, i appreciate it.